# Jquery - Get Attribute using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

This may be something very easy but i can't seem to get this to work and im not sure why. I  have jquery installed and i am trying to get an attribute of "this" element when i click on it.  Right now my code looks like this:

```
url = $(this).attr("href")
```

When I call this function by clicking on a link, it tells me that the var "url" is undefined.  So obviously it is not picking up the "this" when i click on the link. I am trying to pass the href of an anchor tag to use as my variable.

What am i overlooking?  Again, i know this is something very simple but i can't seem to figure it out so thank you for taking the time to help me.

Thanks.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
url = "push1";

$("a").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
    url = $(this).attr("href");
})
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "/"+url+".php",
    data: "",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(html){
        jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
    },

})
;
</script>
```

html:

```
<body>

<a href="push1" >Image 1</a>
<a href="push2" >Image 2</a>  

<div id="Right_Content"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Can we see the rest of the code where this is called? and maybe some of your DOM markup?

Comment: Are you missing the var definition?

Comment: You realise there's a semi-colon missing after the `$('a').live()`, right? Invalid syntax *might* be the problem. Also, a trailing comma from the `success`. And fixing your syntax seems to make it work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/n7RKT/), although obviously the content doesn't load, but I've logged the `url` variable to the console. And [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated, you should use either [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), or [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (the former for jQuery 1.7+, the latter for <1.7).

Comment: You have an illegal comma after your "success" function.

Comment: @ron: The comma there is valid. It's just IE which has problems with it. But it is valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work for you

```
$(function(){    
    $(".link").click(function(){
       var url=$(this).attr("href");
       alert(url);
        return false;

    });       

});​
```

Assuming you are targeting all anchor tags with a css class called "link"

Here is the working example : http://jsfiddle.net/L99mM/2/

**Edit: As per your code posted in the question**

You should call preventDefault after your ajax call. and there is closing brackets should be after ajax call

```
$("a").live("click", function(event) {      
      var targeturl = $(this).attr("href");

      $.ajax({
               type: "get",
               url: "/"+targeturl +".php",
               data: "",
               dataType: "html",
               success: function(html){
                   jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
               }

           });  // closing for  ajax
        event.preventDefault(); 

  });  // closing for click  event binding
```

Comment: Why need jquery object and not standard js? `this.getAttribute("href")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var url = "push1";

function getContent(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/"+url+".php",
        data: "",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(html){
        jQuery('#Right_Content').hide().html(html).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}

$("a").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
    url = $(this).attr("href");
    getContent();
});

getContent();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need "this" for this, you need the target of the event:

```
$("a").live("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();     
    url = event.target.href;
})
```

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/3LvCm/

Comment: I'm thinking that you probably haven't tried that? Because, in Chromium 17/Ubuntu 11.04, all *I* get from that is an error: `Object http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/push1 has no method 'attr'`.

Comment: Why should he not use `this`? It will refer to the element the event was triggered on.

Comment: @DavidThomas - yep noticed that while making the fiddle, edited

Comment: @FelixKling "this" will work (as this fiddle shows http://jsfiddle.net/jUKgs/), but when methods get big and complex it is a lot easier to track event variables than having to try figure out what "this" refers to in that instance. Just a design choice really.